# How can i order by closest match in angular using orderBy

Tags: angularjs

In an `ng-repeat` directive which handles a very long list.
I have a search box that i want to filter by the closest match.

for example:
if i have:

- hello how are you
- hello how are you doing today
- hello brother

and i search for "hello"

i want the "hello brother" to come up first since it is the least amount of characters away from the search string.

Comment: search input[filter] detect your different keyword to filter your results in ng-repeat, when you insert "hello" as keyword, ng-repeat show all strings has this keyword until you complete your keyword with something else like "hello b". [please insert your code]

Comment: You should show us the ng-repeat code you have. So we can more easily determine if your donging something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the number of characters matter more you could sort by string length.

```
orderBy: 'string.length'
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pqotkv3W7ZsU3w0v3B2o?p=preview) is a plunker example. Which doen't make much sense but proves this works.

You could also look into [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) and make a custom sort.

Here is a small example of what you could do

```
app.filter('sortByLength', function() {

  return function(items) {
    items.sort(function (a, b) {    
      return (a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1);
    });
    return items;
  };
});
```

If you want you could bring in the search string as a parameter to the filter look on the angularjs. More info 
 [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

```
app.filter('sortByMatch', function() {
  return function(items, searchString) {
    var re = new RegExp("[" + searchString + "]", "g"); 
    items.sort(function (a, b) { 

      if (!searchString) {
        return input;
      }
      var matchingCharsA = a.length - (a.match(re) || []).length; 
      var matchingCharsB = b.length - (b.match(re) || []).length;

      return (matchingCharsA > matchingCharsB ? 1 : -1);
    });
    return items;
  };
});
```

You can use it like so.

```
ng-repeat="item in.... | sortByMatch: searchString
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What is the purpose of `forEach`?

Comment: Good question! I copied the code from another place. But I'm guessing it should be not to alter the input list. but still have a new list? What do you think?

Comment: I removed it since I'm not quite sure if its necessary.

Comment: You created RegExp but not used in match().
Correct code should be       
var matchingCharsA = a.length - (a.match(re) || []).length; 
var matchingCharsB = b.length - (b.match(re) || []).length;

Comment: Also new RegExp("/[" + searchString + "]/g") is wrong. It should be new RegExp("[" + searchString + "]", "g");

Answer (score 3):

Filter will do the work, at first, angularJS had a default filter for search, so you can use it:

```
ng-repeat="item in .... | filter:searchText"
```

And then build a new filter to order the search result:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tsrFcgwV1npDsYNPeNrk?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('order', function() {
  return function(input, text) {

    if (!text) {
      return input;
    }

    return input.sort(function(a, b) {
       // if a, b is string, or object, you can compare 
       // a.name or b.name
      var ret = a.localeCompare(b);
      return ret; 

    });
  };
});
```

Sorry, misunderstand your question, should compare string length.

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('order', function() {
  return function(input, text) {

    if (!text) {
      return input;
    }

    return input.sort(function(a, b) {

      return a.length - b.length;

    });
  };
});
```

Then chain filter together:

```
ng-repeat="item in.... | filter:searchText | order:searchText"
```